# Write a script to run on different SQL engines

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm writing a SQL script that needs to be able to run on multiple SQL engines, namely SQL Server and Azure SQL.  An `IF` statement checks the database version to execute the correct code.  But the code won't compile if used on the wrong engine.

This works fine in Azure SQL, but SQL Server rejects it.

```
IF (@@VERSION LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Azure %')
BEGIN
    ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO [dbo].[User].[UserName] WITH (LABEL = 'Confidential', INFORMATION_TYPE = 'Credentials')
    ...
END
GO
```

What are my options for ensuring this is accepted by both engines?

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic SQL could be used to circumvent syntax check:

```
IF (@@VERSION LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Azure %')
BEGIN
    EXEC('ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO [dbo].[User].[UserName] WITH (LABEL = ''Confidential'', INFORMATION_TYPE = ''Credentials'')');
    ...
END
GO
```

Please note that all `'` have to be quoted i.e.`''`. [Add support for here-strings i T-SQL](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34385422-add-support-for-here-strings-i-t-sql)

---

[ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-sensitivity-classification-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current) will be supported starting from SQL Server 2019.